# ndk-build.cmd isn't recognized as internal or external command

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I'm working on OpenCV library in android studio.I'm using 2.2.1 version of android studio. Problem is that when I run ndk-build.cmd on command prompt, debugger shows that it is not recognised command,operable program or batch file. 
when I build my project it gives error, that is:

```
" Error:(120) *** Android NDK: Aborting.  Stop."
```

I also have tried to build project without importing OpenCV library as I was following a tutorial, but it also give error.

```
"Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
```

> Error: Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported native build system.
>   Consider using CMake or ndk-build integration with the stable Android Gradle plugin:
>    https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html
>   or use the experimental plugin:
>    http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental."

Even I download CMake and NDK tools but still this error exists. Please guide me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you integrate your ndk with AS ?

Comment: Yes, I have set the path to ndk folder.

Comment: In Android Studio or path of your window ?

Comment: Yes,In android studio

Comment: please show me your build.gradle file of your app module ?

Comment: Are you using mac or window ?

Comment: I'm using windows 8.1

Comment: build.gradle file is too long. Please let me know how I can show it to you.

Comment: you can use pastebin.com for your build.gradle

Comment: @AlexCohn Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Here is buil.gradle file of project that shows the first error of aborting ndk

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MYJj7F4w

Answer (score 2):

To run ndk-build

1)you have to add its path in your Enviroment Variable so yo can access it from anywhere with just "ndk-build.cmd"

or

2) you have to give full ndk path like E:\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd if you have windows

Answer (score 0):

To run ndk-build from command prompt, you can provide the full path to the script, e.g.

```
C:\> d:\android\ndk\ndk-build.cmd
```

It is important to install ndk to a directory with no spaces in its full path, e.g.

```
d:\android SDK\ndk r13
```

won't work. Avoid spaces in the path to your project, too. Android Studio will not be happy to build

```
e:\my projects\android apps\ndk sample\build\outputs\apk\my first ndk app.apk
```

Comment: Here is my ndk path:                                                                                          E:\sdk\ndk-bundle                                                                                            But when I run command, debugger shows that: "Your Android application project path contains spaces"

Comment: Aha! That's right. Avoid spaces in the path to your project, too.

Comment: but path don't have spaces

Comment: can you post exactly how you try to run ndk-build? From which directory, with which params

Comment: Here is how I'm trying to run command:                                                          E:\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd                                                                        *ndk-bundle is folder name.